# Drawing over an image in gimp without downscaling artefacts

Tags: gimp, character-design

So I want to draw a character for my game, by first drawing it on a paper, then scanning it, and then putting it as a bottom layer to GIMP to draw on top of.

My problem is when I try to do this for a low-resolution output image, I get a very blurry backdrop image, like this:

[image: undesirable]

Most displeasant, just before I confirm the scaling down of the original image,
I get a glimpse of what I want:

[image: desirable]

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Your final image seems to be 18 pixels high. Is that wanted? If yes then you should design the shape as 18 pixels high from the start. Pixel artists do it continuously. There's no way to guess automatically what 18 px high pattern looks good when the original was drawn in a way which needs much higher number of pixels.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared. I am not sure what are you suggesting exactly. Yeah, the resulting image should be about that height. But what do you mean by designing it for 18 pixels high from the start? Should I just plot pixels on the paper?

Comment: Do as pixel artists do. Paint single pixels with sharp 1 pixel size brush, be sure no anti-aliasing is ON. Work in computer. Start from empty image which is 18 pixels high. Pixel artists seem to use often Microsoft Paint because it doesn't try to do anything clever. It simply works. Forget paper because it allows you to draw too easily things that cannot be shown properly as pixel art.